# Managing noise in a night scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I've been trying to get a pretty noise free image from this scene for a while. And nothing seems to be working.
I've been trying to use 3000 samples, then rendering different noise seeds and composite them together, but the base images are to noisy to even use this.

I've never really had this much noise before, and I'm not sure what's wrong with it. It already takes around 5-6 hours for me to render it at 3k samples (Laptop, so I cant use GPU rendering). Any help?
I've attached my render settings as well if it helps.
[image]

Here's a link to a bigger version of the photo if it's not large enough
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3swgloty4rt2ef/1430608690119.jpg?dl=0

Someone on another forum suggested I use Luxrender instead, but I'd rather save myself the time in learning a completely new renderer and converting everything.

Comment: Does this image have anything to do with GTA Vice City? Because it reminds me of it...

Comment: Its Ocean Beach from VC, so yeah.